# Is it possible to pipe all browser console messages/errors to a remote machine?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview, inappbrowser

I'm currently trying to debug a javascript error that occurs within a Cordova app's InAppBrowser (on Android). Unfortunately, although I can connect to the web-view on the phone using chrome's remote debugging/inspection tools, the console output is empty, despite the fact that it shouldn't be. (There's misc messages/warnings that should be showing up regardless of hitting the issue or not.)

At this point, I've hit a wall on trying to get the console/error messages. Nothing seems to work. Can anyone think of a way I could tell the webview/javascript to forward all error messages to a remote address? (Obviously, I'd never ship an app with this sort of configuration.)

Comment: Interesting - I've never used the remote debugger but sometimes I'm looking at the wrong context in the console - so first make sure there isn't any dropdown in the settings or something that allow you to change the console context (the primary one will be 'top').  After that you may need to get creative - implementing a dev mode that prints the console errors to the actual view or sends the console outputs to a remote db (I've used firebase for this to get the errors in real time)

Comment: You could use https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre. But if that is too much, you can override console.log to do something else, like calling a REST API. Can't guarantee the performance or stability of the app, if there are many console.logs

Comment: Take a look at sentry.io (free during development , but if you want use it in production it's not free)

Comment: have you tried overriding the console functions in your inAppBrowser code to something you could see on the phone, like an alert , ie, `console.log = function(){alert("Log: " + JSON.stringify(Array.from(arguments)));};`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a JavaScript error, you might be able to catch it with `window.onerror`. The idea is to catch the error then post it to a logging server.

```js
window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
  alert(msg)
  // Log error to external server.
  // axios.post(url, JSON.stringify({msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error}))
}

const test = undefined

test.error
```

I do this in my production environments. This helps to catch errors and notify me of the issue faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested logging errors and other info to another machine you can use the [Reporting API](https://www.w3.org/TR/reporting), where one uses the `Report-To` server header (potentially along with other headers) to enable reporting of specified errors to a reporting endpoint. Here's list of some of the [possible report types](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/reportingapi#reportypes) (more details on [Network Error logging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Network_Error_Logging)). It's currently [supported in Chrome/Edge](https://caniuse.com/mdn-http_headers_report-to), and can be enabled through [about:config in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Reporting_API).